# How long does it take to write a script

Tags: after-effects, youtube, script

I am doing a project in my summer holidays, where I want to produce 2 - 3 youtube clips where people should learn something.

I need volunteers for this, writing the scripts, searching the content, etc. and some for doing the design stuff. The video should be in the style of "In a nutshell", so I'm producing it with the help of Illustrator and AfterEffects.

My question is, how much time is needed to write a script for a 3 minute video, when 2 people work together. In best case, the volunteers writing the script know something about that topic already and don't have to do that much research.

The other question is, how long does it take to make all the graphics and design the video itself, when 3 people are working togehter.

I need to know that in order to find out how much money I should give them. Although it's voluntary, I want to give them something and I really don't know how much I should give them.

PS: I have 1000 € for the whole production and about 10 people should help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about this the wrong way.  First, you already have an established budget and the number of people you want as collaborators.  You can say "I am looking to work with 10 people to write 2-3 minute scripted educational videos.  You pick the topic and send me a super-rough outline.  If I like it, you write the script, and I'll produce the video content using Adobe Illustrator and After Effects.  In addition to receiving writing credit, I'll pay you 100 € if I accept your script for production."  This way, the process is self-selecting.  Whether it takes them 2-3 minutes or 2-3 days to write the script, you'll get the scripts you want within the budget you have and nobody should be disappointed because all the conditions are stated up-front.